# How to get the name of the collection in the document

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

After various researches and tests I decided to write here. I am building an API in Python and I am using Firebase-Admin SDK. On Firestore I have a database with many collections and subcollections, and through this code I can take the documents present in the final collection. My problem/doubt is how to get the collection names. Specifically, I want to get all the names of the collections present in a document.

My code:

```python
    collections = firestore.collection('schools').document(regione).collection(provincia).document(comune).collections()
    for collection in collections:
        for doc in collection.stream():
            print(f'{doc.id} => {doc.to_dict()}')
```

Result:

```python
    0 => {' INFORMATICA': {'1C ART': 'test'}}
    school_info => {'school_name': 'Test school 1', 'indirizzo': 'Address 1'}
    
    0 => {' INFORMATICA': {'3C ART': 'ggf8'}}
    1 => {'TELECOMUNICAZIONI': {'4C TEL': '26753g'}}
    school_info => {'school_name': 'Test school 2', 'indirizzo': 'Address 2'}
```

Instead I would like to take only the names of the collections, without overloading the database by entering all the subcollections:

```
Test school 1
Test school 2
```

I want to clarify that I have already done some research on the web and I have not arrived at any solution for the admin SDK in Python. Thanks in advance

My structure:

```
Schools (collection) -> Lombardia (document) -> Milan (collection) ->
Milan (document) -> Test School 1 (collection) -> 0 (document) -> various fields
```

Comment: `collections = firestore.collection('schools').document(regione).collection(provincia).document(comune).collections()` so what are you looking to do exactly with this? You don't want the documents inside of the collections? you just want the names of the collections?

Comment: Yes, with the code I use I take the documents in the last subdocument. Instead, I want to take the names of the collections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sample code, `Test School 1` and `Test School 2` are subcollections inside the `Milan` document. If you need to fetch the names of all these subcollections from `Milan`, you can call the [`collections()`](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/client.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1.async_client.AsyncClient.collections) method as you were doing, since this returns an iterator of all the collections in a specific reference location (in this case, the Milan document).

The iterator is of type [`CollectionReference`](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/_modules/google/cloud/firestore_v1/base_collection.html#BaseCollectionReference), and this class has the convenient property of `id`, which simply returns the collection name without having to fetch any documents from the collections themselves. I quickly set up a test based on your structure to show this:

```python
fire_db = firestore.client()

collections = fire_db.collection("Schools").document("Lombardia").collection("Milan").document("Milan").collections()

for collection in collections:
    print(collection.id) # Gets id property of each iterated collection reference
```

Output:

```
Test School 1
Test School 2
```

Let’s say instead you want to use the metadata document `school_info` to fetch the names from there. In that case, you can travel to that document by using each `CollectionReference` that is iterated over to get that specific document, and fetch the `school_name` from the document (produces the same output as above):

```python
fire_db = firestore.client()

collections = fire_db.collection("Schools").document("Lombardia").collection("Milan").document("Milan").collections()

for collection in collections:
    print(collection.document("school_info").get().get("school_name")) # Fetches each school_info document, and then retrieves the school_name
```